# Source for heicha kedusha?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, tefilla, tefillah-betzibbur, heiche-kedusha

What is the source in halacha that says heicha kedusha is a valid way for a minyan to cover chazara hshatz?

By heicha kedusha I mean the practice of the chazan (person leading prayer) to start the amidah prayer initially out loud as one would for the repetition and after the responsive section known as kedusha is finished to then complete silently thus covering both the repetition to include kedusha as well as the silent amidah prayer

edit note. I am not asking about the bracha concluding kedusha but about the practice of heicha kedusha. this is not a repeat

Comment: What do you mean by "the source"? Do you mean the first known written source? The derivation of the law? Sources from modern Poskim? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: BY OC 124 in name of KolBo

Comment: Also clarify if you are asking about when the tzibur starts amida along with the chazzon or waits till after Kedusha to start their amida.

Comment: I've heard that in Slobodka the talmidim were mezalzel chazaras hashatz, and so the Rabbanan decided to cut Mincha short to prevent that.

Comment: @sabbahillel not a repeat as the question isn't about lador vador but about where the practice of heicha kedusha comes from

Comment: Laser123 Only one question per post, please. If you also want to ask when one should begin their silent Amida, you can ask that separately. In this post you should consider specifying which practice you refer to, if you care.

Comment: ok. I only added that part b/c of a comment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many different variations of the Heicha Kedusha,but I will bring what I think is one of the first sources.

**The Bais Yosef in Orach Chaim 232:1** writes that if a tzibbur sees that the day is about to end and they need to pray mincha but there isnt enough time to pray the amidah and chazaras hashatz then the tzibbur should pray the amidah (silent shmoneh esrei) first since that is the more important part and one is yotzei from the silent shmoneh esrei. He then brings that after that if there isn't time for the whole repetition then the shaliach tzibur should say from beg until HaKel Hakadosh. This was brought in the name of Rav Hai Gaon and this is how they were noheg in the yeshiva of Pumbadita.

**The Rama 124:2** writes that the tzibbur should say word for word with the shaliach tzibbur until haKel Hakodesh,and he notes that there should be at least one person to answer amen to the Shaliach tzibbur (brings this from the Maharil).

**The Mishna Brurah 124:8** notes that if they wont miss the zman of mincha then the tzibbur should not say word for word with the shaliach tzibbur but rather start their silent SE after haKel Hakodosh.

In **MTJ (Mesivta Tiferes Yerushalyim)** they daven a heicha kedusah everyday at mincha time. They follow the procedure of the Mishna Brurah.

**Text of the Bais Yosef:**

א וכשיגיע זמן תפלת המנח' יתפלל ומאוד צריך ליזהר בה דאמר ר' חלבו אמר רב הונא לעולם יזהר אדם בתפלת המנחה וכו' בפ"ק דברכות (ו:): גרסינן בפרק תפלת השחר (כט:) א"ר חייא בר אבא א"ר יוחנן מצוה להתפלל עם דמדומי חמה וא"ר זירא מאי קרא ייראוך עם שמש ולפני ירח דור דורים לייטי עלה במערבא אמאן דמצלי עם דמדומי חמה מ"ט דילמא מטרפא ליה שעתא ופירש"י עם דמדומי חמה. תפלת יוצר עם הנץ החמה ותפלת המנחה עם שקיעת החמה: לייטי עלה במערבא. על מי שמשהה תפלת המנחה עם דמדומי חמה שמא תטרף לו השעה ע"י אונס ועבר הזמן: והגה"מ כתבו בפ"ג ועתה נהגו העולם כרבנן להתפלל עד הערב וכרבי יוסי דאמר בירושלמי דלא הוקשה תפלת מנח' לתמיד של בין הערביים אלא לקטרת שנאמר תכון תפלתי קטרת לפניך ואמר ר' חייא בר אבא א"ר יוחנן מצוה להתפלל עם דמדומי חמה ואע"ג דלייטי עלה במערבא ה"מ מאן דמאחר טפי אבל קודם ביאת שמש מעט ש"ד כדאמרינן בירושלמי רבי יוסי הוה מצלי עם דמדומי חמה שנאמר על זאת יתפלל כל חסיד אליך לעת מצוא לעת מצויו של יום ואע"ג דתפלת המנחה זמנה מו' שעות ומחצה עד הערב מ"מ מאן דמצלי מפלג מנחה קטנה ולמטה עדיף טפי ובלבד שלא ידחוק את השעה עכ"ל : ‏

**Main part starts here:**

כתוב **בשבלי הלקט שכתב רבינו אפרים בשם רבינו האי** דציבור דדחיקא להו שעתא ביני שמשי אית להו לצלויי בלחש והדר לנחותי ש"ץ דלית ליה לש"ץ למיחת ולאפוקינהו **י"ח בקול רם** לפי שמצות תפלה בלחש ולא נפקי י"ח בין יחיד בין ציבור אלא בלחש ותקנתייהו דמצלי כולהו בלחש במצות תפלה והדר נחית ש"ץ ואומר מגן ומחיה וענו קדושה ומסיים האל הקדוש אם אין שהות ביום למיגמר י"ח ברכות והכי נהוג רבנן במתיבתא כד דחיקא להו שעתא וכן ראוי לעשות עכ"ל :‏

**Text of Rama:**

הַגָּה: וְכֵן אִם הוּא שְׁעַת הַדַּחַק, כְּגוֹן שֶׁיָּרֵא שֶׁיַּעֲבֹר זְמַן הַתְּפִלָּה, יוּכַל לְהִתְפַּלֵּל מִיָּד בְּקוֹל רָם, וְהַצִּבּוּר מִתְפַּלְּלִין עִמּוֹ מִלָּה בְּמִלָּה בְּלַחַשׁ עַד לְאַחַר הָאֵל הַקָּדוֹשׁ, וְטוֹב שֶׁיִּהְיֶה אֶחָד לְכָל הַפָּחוֹת שֶׁיַּעֲנֶה אָמֵן אַחַר הַשְּׁלִיחַ צִבּוּר (מַהֲרִי''ל). ‏

**Text of the Mishna Brurah:**

(ח) והצבור וכו' - ואם אין השעה דחוקה כ"כ לא יתחילו הצבור רק לאחר שאמר הש"ץ האל הקדוש: ‏

Comment: The Rema argues,but I did not add that since I thought you were asking about when this started,but if you want more of a halcha lamaaseh let me know and will put in the Rema and Mishna Brurab and what Yeshivas actually do

Comment: thanks for your answer. if you could include their reasoning as well that would improve your answer

Comment: include whos reasoning

Comment: rema and mishna beruru which you offered to include in your comment

Comment: Interesting that none of the quotes you list OK it for Shacharis, only Mincha.  Is there one to add for the morning?  Does it exist?

Comment: @mike some of these sources are about Shacharit. Like Rama 124

Comment: @MikeSupportsMonica, often there is more reason to do so for mincha.  The SA's case is that the time for tefila will soon end, which seems more common for mincha than shacharit.  That said, shacharit could have "people need to leave for work. Heicha kedusha or we won't have a minyan" though in that case I believe one might be permitted to say the repetition anyway as long as the minyan was there for the start.

Answer (score 0):

The source for a heicha kedusha probably comes from how they used to be "poreis al shma", which is discussed in shulchan aruch OC 69 in the Rema.

Comment: Please give the details.